# rendering transparency in eevee is WHITE background

Tags: rendering

trying to export with transparent background in Blender 3.  Always end up with white background no matter what I do.   I did a test on a new project and was successfully able to export with transparent background... so that at least means I know how to do it in theory.   However something is preventing it in my current job and I have no idea what it might be.

thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/axbd1wa1fsvz1rl/Phospholipids+and+brownian+motion2.blend/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your *Compositor* setup, that's why you end up with a white background. You either need to remove your *Alpha Over* or disable the *Compositing* option in the *Output panel > Post Processing*.

[image]